# Contractibility of the based path space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $x_0 \in X.$ Consider the based path space $$\mathcal P_{x_0} (X) : = \left \{\gamma : [0,1] \xrightarrow{\text {continuous}} X\ \bigg |\ \gamma (0) = x_0 \right \}$$ of $X$ at $x_0$ equipped with the compact open topology. Then we get a deformation retract $H : \mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathcal P_{x_0} (X)$ between $P_{x_0} (X)$ and the constant path $c_{x_0}$ at $x_0$ given by $$H (\gamma, s) = \gamma ((1 - s) \cdot) : t \mapsto  \gamma ((1 - s) t).$$ But I am having hard time to show that this map is continuous. In order to show that $H$ is continuous it is enough to show that the inverse image of subbasic open sets in $\mathcal P_{x_0} (X)$ with respect to compact open topology under the map $H$ is open. Any such subbasic open set is of the form $U_{K, V} : =\left \{\gamma \in \mathcal P_{x_0} (X)\ \big |\ \gamma (K) \subseteq V \right \},$ where $K \subseteq [0,1]$ is compact and $V \subseteq X$ is open. Now what will be $H^{-1} (U_{K, V})\ $? It contains all those $(\gamma, s) \in \mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times [0,1]$ such that $\gamma ((1 - s) K) \subseteq V$ i.e. $\gamma \in U_{(1 - s)K, V}$ and this implies $$H^{-1} (U_{K, V}) = \bigcup\limits_{s \in [0,1]} U_{(1 - s) K, V} \times \{s \}.$$ But why is it open in the product topology?

Any suggestion in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fun Fact** $1$ $:$ Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces with $Y$ locally compact. Then the evaluation map $ev : Y^X \times X \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous, where $Y^X$ is the set of all continuous maps from $X$ to $Y.$

**Fun Fact** $2$ $:$ Let $X, Y$ and $Z$ be topological spaces. Then any continuous map $f : X \times Y \longrightarrow Z$ induces a continuous map $F : X \longrightarrow Z^Y.$ The converse is true if $X$ is locally compact which follows from the above theorem just by observing that given $F : X \longrightarrow Z^Y,$ the induced map $f : X \times Y \xrightarrow{} Z$ is obtained via the following composition $:$

$$X \times Y \xrightarrow{F \times \text{id}} Z^Y \times Y \xrightarrow{ev} Z$$

**Why does the required result follow from the above two facts?** $:$

In our problem replace $X$ by $\mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times I,$ $Y$ by $I$ and $Z$ by $X.$ Since $I$ is locally compact it follows from the above facts that the continuity of the map $H : \mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times I \longrightarrow \mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \subseteq X^I$ defined by $$(\gamma, s) \longrightarrow \gamma ((1 - s) \cdot) : t \mapsto \gamma ((1 - s)t)$$ is equivalent to the continuity of the map $\widetilde H : \mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times I \times I \longrightarrow X$ defined by $(\gamma, s, t) \mapsto \gamma ((1 - s) t).$ The later map is continuous as it is the composition of the following two continuous maps $:$

$$\mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times I \times I \xrightarrow{\text {id} \times \delta} \mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times I \xrightarrow{ev\ \big \rvert_{\mathcal P_{x_0} (X) \times I}} X$$ where $\delta : I \times I \longrightarrow I$ is the continuous map defined by $(s,t) \mapsto (1 - s) t.$

Hence the result follows. $\blacksquare$

Comment: For the proof of the sbove facts, please have a look at **Proposition A.14** in the **Appendix** [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) in Hatcher's **Algebraic Topology**.